# What is the most important thing to look for when buying a used trailer frame?

Tags: construction, metal

I'm planning to build a camper. Saw some used trailer frames on craigslist. I'm concerned that I might buy a frame that I won't be able to use.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider  how much it will weigh. When built. Will you need just one axle? Or more.  Look for rust, cracks along the frame.  Look for  anything that might be bent.

Comment: Most of the ones from craiglist have rust on them like this one http://www.kijiji.ca/v-cargo-utility-trailer/london/trailer-frames-of-all-types-and-sizes/1253045934?enableSearchNavigationFlag=true       ------------ Would that be a problem?

Comment: @aboat depends on if it is just surface rust that you can sand of and paint over or deeper rust that needs to be cut out and replaced.

Comment: regarding the age of the trailer frame how old is too old? as a newbie how can i see deep rust without sanding? did sand before, but not enough to see a difference with the naked eye. I'm not sure whether the seller will let me sand it and see if it goes off in front of him.

Comment: The age isn't as important as how well it's been taken care of. If the seller won't let you check the extent of the rust, then there's no way of knowing just by looking just how deep it may go. You need to tap it with a small hammer, sand it, or use a wire brush on a cordless drill, or even grind it.

Answer (score 1):

about, You'll want a frame that is free of rust through spots. Surface rust can be sanded and painted. Also, you'll also want to find out when the bearings and seals were replaced last. I don't know how large of a camper project your planning. Just be sure to get one big enough based on GVRW= Gross Vehicle Weight Rating. The weight of the camper material plus the trailer weight, and then get a little higher GVWR, rating of the frame. Good Luck!

Comment: Are the bearings and seals important? After doing some research, I realized those are cheap and easy to replace. Did I misunderstand?